# Como fazer um select dinâmico?

Tags: php, javascript

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou fazendo um sisteminha de restaurante, e ele é uma comanda. Mas, tipo, tem um `select` de pedidos de comidas, mas eu queria saber como posso fazer pra quando eu clicar no sinal de + apareça outro `select` embaixo do que já tem para fazer o pedidos de outra comida, pois nem sempre o cliente quer só uma coisa.

Estou fazendo o sistema com PHP e JavaScript.

Comment: Você não tem nenhum código de teste? Quer isso com javascript ou pode ser com jquery?

Comment: Uma ideia seria um botão (+) que ao ser clicado, cria um objeto html do tipo DIV com um id e um name incrementáveis e dentro dessa div outro select com as mesmas opções. Na hora de submeter o formulário, Será necessário ver se o cliente escolheu em selects diferentes o mesmo produto e tratar a repetição ou, na criação da div, já colocar o select anterior disabled e retirar da lista de opções do novo    select criado a opçao selecionada anteriormente. Isso vai dar uma mão de obra boa!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seria isso?
Em vez de ao selecionar aparecer outro select, fiz um exemplo que ao selecionar adiciona um input com o valor que foi adicionado.

```js
$(".add").on('click',function(){
var cont=0;
$("#selecionados input").each(function(){
if($(this).val()==$("#selecionar option:selected").html()){
cont++;
 }
});
if(cont>0){ alert("Este item ja esta adicionado, altere a quantidade se deseja mais..");}
else{
$("#selecionados").append("<input disabled type='text' name='pedidos[]' value='"+$("#selecionar option:selected").html()+"' ><input type='text' name='quantidade[]' placeholder='quantidade'><br>");
}
});
```

```css
.add{ text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selecionar">
<option selected isabled>Selecione</option>
<option>Pao</option>
<option>Leite</option>
<option>Cafe</option>
</select>
<a class="add" href="#">+</a>
<hr>
Selecionados
<hr>
<div id="selecionados">
  
</div>
```

E no php voce pegaria o valor em array, assim:

```
<?php $valores=$_POST['pedidos'] 
foreach($valores as $item){
echo $item."<br>";
}


?>
```

Comment: Sim assim mesmo ficou top. obrigado. Mas e como fazer pra mostrar a quantidades que foi pedida de cada um ?

Comment: Voce pode ou fazer a veirificação no php, ou adicionar ao lado o input, outro input com a quantidade

Comment: @allanaraujo Assim?Editei ali Se solucinou sua dúvida, marque como resposta :)

Comment: Obrigado ficou ótimo.

Comment: @allanaraujo De nada, coloquei a verificação se o item ja esta adicionado tambem...

Comment: Mas me diz uma coisa quando eu for enviar a informação para o banco de dados tenho que fazer apenas uma coluna para o pedido de comida ou várias para cada item adicionado ?

Comment: @allanaraujo recomendo voce fazer duas tabelas, uma pedido e outra item_pedido, na pedido, voce armazena o valor, data, cliente e tal. Na item_pedido, voce armazena o id do pedido, e cada item adicionado.

Comment: irei usar esse sistema apenas em localhost , coloquei tudo mais ele não funciona . Só funciona aqui no site mais em localhost ele não acrescenta nada . o que poderia fazer

Comment: @allanaraujo abra uma nova pergunta e especifique tudo para poder lhe ajuda melhor

Comment: já fiz a pergunta

Comment: como eu poderia fazer essa query ? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178382/armazenar-m%C3%BAltiplos-select-numa-coluna-s%C3%B3-com-php-javascript-mysql/