# Armazenar múltiplos select numa coluna só com PHP/javascript + MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com dificuldade em armazenar múltiplos select em um mesmo campo da tabela. Neste caso, ao preencher o formulário e marcar mais de um select, ele armazena somente um e o campo de quantidade do  input que é em javascript não armazena .
Como poderia fazer pra armazenar tudo

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

//Criar a conexao
$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "peixaria");
if($link->connect_errno){
     echo"Nossas falhas local experiência ..";
     exit();
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $numero_mesa = $_POST['numero_mesa'];
    $pedido_refeicao = $_POST['pedido_refeicao'];
    $num_refeicao = $_POST['num_refeicao'];
    $pedido_bebida = $_POST['pedido_bebida'];
    $num_bebida = $_POST['num_bebida'];
        $sql="INSERT INTO mpedido(numero_mesa,pedido_refeicao,num_refeicao,pedido_bebida,num_bebida) VALUES('$numero_mesa','$pedido_refeicao','$num_refeicao','$pedido_bebida','$num_bebida')";
        $resultado_pedido = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

}
?>



<form method="post" action="pedidos.php">
                <header>
                    <h2>Fazer Pedido</h2>
                </header>
                <fieldset>
                    <label>
                        <span>Mesa</span>
                        <input type="text"id="numero_mesa" name="numero_mesa">
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>Comanda:</span>

                    </label>
                    <span>Refeições/Bebidas/Sobremesas:</span>
                    <div class="pedidos">

                        <select name="pedido_refeicao" id="pedido_refeicao"class="selecionar">
                            <option selected disabled>Selecione</option>
                            <option >Costela de Tambaqui sem Espinha</option> 
                            <option  >Lombo de Tambaqui Frito sem Espinha</option>
                            <option >Caldeirada de Tambaqui sem Espinha</option>
                            <option >Caldeirada de Tucunaré</option> 
                            <option >Peixe no Tucupi com Camarão</option>
                            <option >Escabeche de Pirarucu</option>
                            <option >Escabeche de Tambaqui</option>
                            <option >Escabeche de Tucunaré</option>
                            <option >Tucunaré Frito</option> 
                            <option >Sardinha Frita</option>
                            <option >Jaraqui Frito</option>
                            <option >Pacu Frito</option> 
                            <option >Filé de Pirarucu Frito</option>
                            <option >Filé de Pirarucu a Milanesa</option>
                            <option >Guisado de Pirarucu</option>
                        </select>
                        <a class="add" href="#">+</a>
                        <hr>
                        Selecionados
                        <hr>
                        <div class="selecionados">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                   <br>
                    <div  class="pedidos">

                        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                        <select name="pedido_bebida" id="pedido_bebida"class="selecionar">
                            <option selected disabled>Selecione</option> 
                            <option >Fanta Laranja 1l</option> 
                            <option >Fanta Laranja 2l</option> 
                            <option >Cola Cola 1l</option>
                            <option >Cola Cola 2l</option>
                            <option >Bare 2l</option> 
                            <option >Fanta Uva</option>
                            <option >Fanta Laranja</option>
                            <option >Sprit</option> 
                            <option >Cola Cola </option>
                            <option >Cola Cola zero </option>
                            <option >Guaraná Antarctica</option> 
                            <option >Guaraná Baré</option>
                            <option >Suco Goiaba</option> 
                            <option >Suco Manga</option>
                            <option >Suco Pessego</option>
                            <option >Suco Uva</option> 
                            <option >Suco Maracujá</option>
                            <option >Suco Laranja</option>
                            <option >Suco Caju</option> 
                            <option >Agua Mineral </option>
                            <option >Agua com Gas </option>
                            <option >Cerveja em Lata</option> 
                            <option >Limonada Natural</option>
                        </select>
                        <a class="add" href="#">+</a>
                        <hr>
                        Selecionados
                        <hr>
                        <div class="selecionados">

                        </div>

                    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="btn" type="submit">Fazer Pedido</button>   
                </fieldset>

            </form>
        </main>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            $(".add").on('click',function(){ 
                var cont=0;
                var holder = $(this).closest('.pedidos');
                holder.find(".selecionados input").each(function(){
                    if($(this).val()==holder.find(".selecionar option:selected").html()){
                        cont++;
                    }
                });
                if(cont>0) { 
                    alert("Este item ja esta adicionado, altere a quantidade se deseja mais..");
                } else{
                    holder.find(".selecionados").append(
                        "<input disabled type='text' name='pedidos[]' value='" + 
                        holder.find(".selecionar option:selected").html() + 
                        "' ><input type='text' name='quantidade[]' placeholder='quantidade'><br>"
                    );
                }
            });


        </script>

    </body>
```

Comment: Amigo pra mim sua dúvida não ficou clara.

Comment: bem meu sistema é de pedido . eu irei fazer pedido de várias coisas , tipo posso seleciona mais de 5 coisas e queria colocar no minha tabela todos os select

Comment: Todas as opções selecionadas no select correto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom para armazenar múltiplas opções de um `select` ele dever ter a seguinte estrutura:

```
<select name="pedido_bebida[]" id="pedido_bebida"class="selecionar" multiple>
```

Ou seja deve adicionar o atributo `multiple` e informar que o `name` é um array.

Já para inserir no banco seria algo como :

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $pedido_bebida = implode(', ', $_POST['pedido_bebida']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sua_tabela(sua_coluna) VALUES ('$pedido_bebida')";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql) OR die(mysqli_error($con));
}
?>
```

A parte do `javascript` se vai fazer a mesma coisa...

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $pedido_bebida = implode(', ', $_POST['pedido_bebida']);
    $quantidade = implode(', ', $_POST['quantidade']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sua_tabela(sua_coluna_bebida, sua_coluna_quantidade) VALUES ('$pedido_bebida', '$quantidade')";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql) OR die(mysqli_error($con));
}
?>
```

Comment: A parte em javascript é que nem sempre o cliente quer só uma coisa ai ao clicar em + ele abre outro select embaixo e um input texto ao lado do select pra colocar a quantidade de item , como posso fazer pra esse input  do javascript ir para o bd ?

Comment: ma eu tenho que inserir no banco de dados numero_mesa e no select pedido_refeicao, num_refeicao,pedido_bebida,num_bebida como faço ?

Comment: Pensa assim cada campo do `html` tem um `name`, o valor desse `input` você vai receber pelo php através da variável `$_POST['name_input']` e vc pode colocar em uma variável), ai com esse valor vc faz uma query sql ou um select ou um insert.....

Comment: pois é é assim que tá , atualizei a pergunta de como ele tá nesse momento , fui fazer da maneira que você respondeu , ele só input a bebida e só uma nem a quantidade ele inseri ,

Comment: dessa forma ele só está enviando um name . queria poder enviar todos com o implode

Answer (score 0):

A mesma coisa que o @MagicHat falou, usando o `name` dos inputs dessa forma `name="name-input[]"` assim você poderá adicionar quantos inputs quiser no form e o PHP receberá como se fosse um array, porém como foi exemplificado anteriormente ficará aberta uma vulnerabilidade muito explorada nas aplicações web que é o SQLInjection então trate qualquer variável que venha informações dos usuários antes de fazer qualquer outra coisa com ela.

Comment: O problema do `SQLinjection` ao meu ver não está no modo como o `html` recebe os dados e sim como vc trata eles na `querie`...

Comment: Sim exatamente por isso que ao receber os dados no backend eles devem ser tratados, para quando chegarem nas ``querys`` chegarem de forma "limpa".